# How to remove border-collapse from p:dataTable?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I want to remove `border-collapse` from `<p:dataTable>`. I tried several ways but no luck here is what I've tried so far:

First:

```css
.ui-datatable table {
    border-collapse: hidden !important;
}
```

Second:

```css
.ui-datatable table {
    border-collapse: none !important;
}
```

Third:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{JpublicCalendar.public_day_1_list}"
             var="o"
             styleClass="value">
    <p:column>
        <h:graphicImage value="PrivateDisplayImage?id=#{o.id}"
                        width="126"
                        height="64">
        </h:graphicImage>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

CSS for it:

```css
.value {
    border: none !important;
    border-collapse: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following css style:

```
.value table * {
       border: none !important;
   }
```